# infinitive : complement or purpose

Tags: meaning-in-context, infinitives

> It is important to gain data ***to verify or falsify your assumption about business model***.

Does the infinitive act as a purpose, being same as **in order to**,

Or does it act as an object complement by describing the intended or desired action of the noun **data**.

Or are both interpretations possible?

Comment: Object complements consist of NPs and AdjPs, never clauses. So I'm inclined to say it's a purpose adjunct.

Comment: And an action or purpose is not necessarily implied by _data_, so that's a semantic reason to doubt that it is a complement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *It is important to gain data* [*to verify or falsify your assumption*
>   *about business model*].

Object complements consist of NPs and AdjPs, but never clauses.

So the bracketed infinitival clause can only be a purpose adjunct. Note the possibility of inserting "in order", which freely occurs with such adjuncts.

Comment: Thanks! Consider this sentence," I asked him to finish my work.", what should we call the infinitive in this sentence?

Comment: @Kathy "Ask" is a catenative verb, and "to finish my homework" is its catenative complement. The intervening noun "him" is the syntactic object of "ask", but only the _understood_ subject of "finish".

Comment: Thank you again for the answer, I will have a look at catenative verb !

Comment: @Kathy  This may help: [link](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-catenative-verb-1689832)